# Error nova-chart deployment for Openstack/helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, openstack-nova

I'm trying to deploy Openstack following the openstack-helm deployment
with NFS  following [openstack-helm-deployment](https://docs.openstack.org/openstack-helm/latest/install/developer/deploy-with-nfs.html)

When I launch the nova-chart to deploy nova services, I got this error
on the nova-compute pod

```
2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service [req-11d17c73-10fb-4fad-abc0-ddf4805267e9 - - - - -] Error starting thread.
    2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service Traceback (most recent call last):
    2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service   File "/var/lib/openstack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_service/service.py", line 722, in run_service
    2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service     service.start()
    2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service   File "/var/lib/openstack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/service.py", line 180, in start
    2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service     self.rpcserver.start()
    2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service   File "/var/lib/openstack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/server.py", line 268, in wrapper
    2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service     log_after, timeout_timer)
    2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service   File "/var/lib/openstack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/server.py", line 188, in run_once
    2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service     post_fn = fn()
    2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service   File "/var/lib/openstack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/server.py", line 267, in <lambda>
    2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service     states[state].run_once(lambda: fn(self, *args, **kwargs),
    2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service   File "/var/lib/openstack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/server.py", line 420, in start
    2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service     self.listener = self._create_listener()
    2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service   File "/var/lib/openstack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/server.py", line 143, in _create_listener
    2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service     return self.transport._listen(self._target, 1, None)
    2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service   File "/var/lib/openstack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/transport.py", line 110, in _listen
    2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service     target)
    2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service InvalidTarget: A server's target must have topic and server names specified:<Target topic=compute>
    2020-07-01 15:28:48.487 7036 ERROR oslo_service.service 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/var/lib/openstack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/queue.py", line 118, in switch
        self.greenlet.switch(value)
      File "/var/lib/openstack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 214, in main
        result = function(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/var/lib/openstack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_service/service.py", line 725, in run_service
        raise SystemExit(1)
    SystemExit: 1
```

this is my nova.conf file

the conf file has beeen saved as secrets, i delete the passwors for security purposes

```
[DEFAULT]
compute_driver = libvirt.LibvirtDriver
cpu_allocation_ratio = 3
default_ephemeral_format = ext4
disk_allocation_ratio = 1
firewall_driver = nova.virt.firewall.NoopFirewallDriver
instance_usage_audit = true
instance_usage_audit_period = hour
linuxnet_interface_driver = openvswitch
log_config_append = /etc/nova/logging.conf
metadata_port = 80
metadata_workers = 1
my_ip = 0.0.0.0
notify_on_state_change = vm_and_task_state
osapi_compute_listen = 0.0.0.0
osapi_compute_listen_port = 8774
osapi_compute_workers = 1
ram_allocation_ratio = 1
resume_guests_state_on_host_boot = true
state_path = /var/lib/nova
transport_url = rabbit://nova:@rabbitmq-rabbitmq-0.rabbitmq.openstack.svc.cluster.local:5672,nova:@rabbitmq-rabbitmq-1.rabbitmq.openstack.svc.cluster.local:5672/nova
use_neutron = true
[api_database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://nova:password@mariadb.openstack.svc.cluster.local:3306/nova_api
max_retries = -1
[cache]
backend = dogpile.cache.memcached
enabled = true
memcache_servers = memcached.openstack.svc.cluster.local:11211
[cell0_database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://nova:password@mariadb.openstack.svc.cluster.local:3306/nova_cell0
max_retries = -1
[conductor]
workers = 1
[database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://nova:@mariadb.openstack.svc.cluster.local:3306/nova
max_retries = -1
[glance]
api_servers = http://glance-api.openstack.svc.cluster.local:9292/
num_retries = 3
[ironic]
api_endpoint = http://ironic-api.openstack.svc.cluster.local:6385/
auth_type = password
auth_url = http://keystone-api.openstack.svc.cluster.local:5000/v3
auth_version = v3
memcache_secret_key = 
memcache_servers = memcached.openstack.svc.cluster.local:11211
password = 
project_domain_name = service
project_name = service
region_name = RegionOne
user_domain_name = service
username = ironic
[keystone_authtoken]
auth_type = password
auth_uri = http://keystone-api.openstack.svc.cluster.local:5000/v3
auth_url = http://keystone-api.openstack.svc.cluster.local:5000/v3
auth_version = v3
memcache_secret_key = 
memcache_security_strategy = ENCRYPT
memcached_servers = memcached.openstack.svc.cluster.local:11211
password = password
project_domain_name = service
project_name = service
region_name = RegionOne
user_domain_name = service
username = nova
[libvirt]
connection_uri = qemu+tcp://127.0.0.1/system
cpu_mode = none
disk_cachemodes = network=writeback
hw_disk_discard = unmap
images_rbd_ceph_conf = /etc/ceph/ceph.conf
images_rbd_pool = vms
images_type = qcow2
rbd_secret_uuid = 457eb676-33da-42ec-9a8c-9293d545c337
rbd_user = cinder
virt_type = qemu
[neutron]
auth_type = password
auth_url = http://keystone-api.openstack.svc.cluster.local:5000/v3
auth_version = v3
metadata_proxy_shared_secret = password
password = password
project_domain_name = service
project_name = service
region_name = RegionOne
service_metadata_proxy = true
url = http://neutron-server.openstack.svc.cluster.local:9696/
user_domain_name = service
username = neutron
[oslo_concurrency]
lock_path = /var/lib/nova/tmp
[oslo_messaging_notifications]
driver = messagingv2
[oslo_messaging_rabbit]
rabbit_ha_queues = true
[oslo_middleware]
enable_proxy_headers_parsing = true
[oslo_policy]
policy_file = /etc/nova/policy.yaml
[placement]
auth_type = password
auth_url = http://keystone-api.openstack.svc.cluster.local:5000/v3
auth_version = v3
os_region_name = RegionOne
password = 
project_domain_name = service
project_name = service
user_domain_name = service
username = placement
[service_user]
auth_type = password
send_service_user_token = false
[spice]
html5proxy_host = 0.0.0.0
server_listen = 0.0.0.0
[upgrade_levels]
compute = auto
[vnc]
enabled = true
novncproxy_base_url = http://novncproxy.openstack.svc.cluster.local/vnc_auto.html
novncproxy_host = 0.0.0.0
novncproxy_port = 6080
vncserver_listen = 0.0.0.0
[wsgi]
api_paste_config = /etc/nova/api-paste.ini
```

all other services of nova are running